# esxcli software install returns with Error: Unknown command or namespace software install

Tags: esxi, vmware-server

When attempting to load a vib onto an ESXi 6.5 installation

```
[root@myserver:~] esxcli software install
```

I get the error:

```
Error: Unknown command or namespace software install
```

Has anybody seen this error and is it a setting that I am just missed and can get past.  I thought it was an error and I reloaded the hypervisor to a slightly newer version, however I'm getting the same error. Seems like I am missing something simple, however I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

copy your VIB into /tmp and retry.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old topic however for better understanding you should copy/paste the complete output of your issue. In addition to that we are also missing some information here like the version, if the command do exists :

`[root@yourhost] vmware -vl`

`[root@yourhost] esxcli software -h`

To anticipate a bit here is one of the maintenance command used by SysAdmin:

`esxcli software vib install -v /vmfs/volumes/datastore/folder/scsi-driver-udpate.x86_64.vib`

I hope that will help.

Regards,

Regis

Comment: Are you sure this solves the problem? Or is this only a way to gather more information about the setup - then please post this as a comment, not as an answer

Comment: I think this might answer it, if the real point is that `software install` is not the correct syntax and `software vib install` is, but it's not worded very clearly.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error due to incorrect command syntax. I'm guessing you are trying to install a `vib` package.

Instead of doing

```
esxcli software install
```

try

```
esxcli software vib install -v /full/path/package.vib
```

Comment: `esxcli software acceptance set --level=CommunitySupported` for custom packages (for those who land here after googling their way)